# Migrating questions when and why

Tags: discussion

This question was migrated to Motor vehicle maintenanace and repair:

https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/77787/10976

Why? It is clearly not about a motor vehicle and is about the use of power supplies, which means it is surely more relevant on this stack.

Comment: The key thing to keep in mind is that just because a question is off topic *here* does not mean that there's any other site where it is proper.  Bad question are for the most part, bad questions, and stack exchange policy is unambiguous that they are to be closed at the source, and not "dumped" on other sites.

Comment: @ChrisStratton as you can see the mod says it should have been kept here as it is on-topic, so your statement saying it is off-topic here starts you off on the wrong track...

Comment: No, you misread.  It is **off topic here** - but even moreso there.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Then you can tell the mod that it is off-topic here...

Comment: Again, you are misreading.  No moderator has disputed its designation as off topic, only admitted that it should not have been migrated to a site where it is [also] off topic.  If you want to understand *why* it is off topic, look at the first comment: it is a usage question about a cheap *undocumented* product of uncertain origin and entirely depends on the implementation detail of that product.

Comment: @ChrisStratton well as such an expert you should get to and do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I read the question I thought it was about modifying a car or motor cycles 12 cigarette lighter so I moved it. I apologise, it shouldn't have been moved, I am human and I do make mistakes every once in a while (I review 100s of questions on the site each week)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. And thanks for doing what you do.

Comment: A modest mistake. No one will be 100% right. Good job Voltage Spike.